# Evil Morty's speech with "sinister overtones"?

Tags: rick-and-morty

Regarding this quote from *Rick and Morty*:

> This seems like a good time for a drink, and a cold calculated speech with sinister overtones. A speech about politics, about order, brotherhood, power. But speeches are for campaigning. Now is the time for action.

Aren't political speeches supposed to be pleasant to the ears of the listeners? According to my understanding, the phrase "sinister overtones" means having a dark side to something. So why would he want a speech with sinister overtones?

Comment: "Aren't political speeches supposed to be pleasant to the ears of the listeners?" Uhm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inauguration_of_Donald_Trump#Inaugural_address And that's just one of many.

Comment: As per your quote "cold calculated speech about politics" is not equal to "political speech".

Comment: I see. Maybe Evil Morty was longing to hear a speech about order, brotherhood, and power. I guess that would make more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like any speech or conversation tone depends on the audience and the speaker's intentions. Most political speeches are indeed *pleasant to the ears of the listeners* because the speakers are often talking to their constituents and want to keep them on side as this will benefit them reelection. However, in this case, given Evil Morty's actions just before this speech, I would say his intentions were to intimidate the remaining members of the room.

Also with the use of the phrase *sinister overtones* I would say this is a fourth wall joke, of which R&M has many http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Wall_Jokes. The idea that after taking rule a villain will give a sinister speech is a trope (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NewEraSpeech) so Evil Morty seems to be aware of this and is playing on it.